# Query target platform for an anaconda package

Tags: anaconda, conda, bz2

I want to know the target platform for a ananconda .tar.bz2 package. Is there any way to get that without exploding the package?

Answer (score 0):

There is no command as such, but I checked a few packages and found that the below file contains the info, although I am not sure if its a standard.

```
tar xvjf py-1.5.2-py27_0.tar.bz2 info/recipe/conda_build_config.yaml

grep target_platform info/recipe/conda_build_config.yaml
target_platform: win-32
```